# How to read out two columns from table and multiplize them?

Tags: android, sqlite, addition

How can I realize that in Android Java ?
So I mean how can I read out mark and weight, multiplize them and add the next row with the same system?:

[image: tbl_marks]

That is what I have now for list those marks in a ListView:

```
private void fillData() {

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String txt_sub_id = extras.getString("IDFach");
    int test = Integer.parseInt(txt_sub_id);

Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, subid, name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks WHERE subid = '"+test+"';", null);
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
     int intName = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subid");

      do {
          teststring = mCursor.getString(intName);

          String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.KEY_NAME_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_MARK_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_GEWICHT_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_DATUM_MARKS};
          int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_marks_row, R.id.txt_note, R.id.txt_gewicht, R.id.txt_datum};

          SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, mCursor, from, to);
          setListAdapter(notes);
      } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
}
    }
```

This looks like that:

[image]

What I like to have:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to know how I can read those columns from database and handle them... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like below inside do/while loop. Here 4 is index of column name in your query.

```
  int mark=mCursor.getInt(4);
   int wght=mCursor.getInt(5);
```